# Wrong path in mail attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, sendmail

Here i need when file uploaded then i need that file attached and mail to it.But attachment file path wrong.

> Error : Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\test.xlsx'. //<--Wrong file path

Code

```
            for (int i = 0; i < fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles.Count; i++)
        {
            if (fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles[i] != null)
            {
                fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles[i].SaveAs(ServerPath + "\\" + fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles[i].FileName);

                using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
                {
                    if (fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles.Count != null)
                    {
                        string FileName = fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles[i].FileName;
                        mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileName));//<-- Error generate here
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("myemail@email.com", "mypassword");
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.Send(mm);
                    }     
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you filling `fuUploadedFiles`?

Comment: @Kelix this is Telerik rad upload.File correctly uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to use virtual path instead of real path. ATM i think fileName as real path. use result of  ServerPath + "\" + fuUploadedFiles.UploadedFiles[i].FileName inplace of fileName. This should solve the issue